# How I can browse the response of an AJAX request with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

How I can browse this result returned by an AJAX request with jQuery?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [valeur] => 70
            [date] => 2016-02-19 11:46:37
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [valeur] => 40
            [date] => 2016-02-19 11:50:38
        )
)
```

Comment: if this is an ajax requrest, then open your browser console and click the ajax call. you will see the output !

Comment: http://blog.haraldkraft.de/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/firebug-console-ajax-aborted.png

Comment: Is this the result as is or a representation?
Usually, Ajax calls return JSON, XML or HTML.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
function MyFunction(comp_id) {
 var user_id = document.getElementById("user").value;

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "chart.php?q="+comp_id+"&u="+user_id ,
    data: "call=test",
    success: function(student){

  alert(JSON.stringify(student));
   
  
    }
});
}
</script>` and the result Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [valeur] => 70
            [date] => 2016-02-19 11:46:37
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [valeur] => 40
            [date] => 2016-02-19 11:50:38
        )
)

Answer (score 0):

In your Javascript code, you have to tell jQuery that you expect JSON :

```
function MyFunction(comp_id) {
    var user_id = document.getElementById("user").value;
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "chart.php?q=" + comp_id + "&u=" + user_id,
        data: "call=test",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(student) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(student));
        }
    });
}
```

And in you PHP code, you have to serialize your array before sending it :

```
echo json_encode($your_array);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: alert(JSON.stringify(student, null, 2)); will do a much better job at being human readable

Comment: @phenxd I did not modify that part of chems code, I have only added `dataType: 'json',`.